# Custom build validation statement on an iterator

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

What's the quickest way (processing sense) to iterate over a list and validate them according to set flags?
Or, in other words, what's the optimal approach to filter list with statement depending on configuration.

Example below is on a list of strings and depending on flags I'd like to filter some of them.

```
class Validator(object):
  def __init__(self, digit=False, tag=False, short=False):
    self.digit = digit
    self.tag = tag
    self.short = short

  def __call__(self, words):
    good_words = []
    for word in words:
      if self.digit:
        if word.is_digit(): continue
      if self.tag:
        if word[0] == "<": continue
      if self.short:
        if len(word) < 3: continue
      good_words.append(word)

    return good_words
```

Use of `Validator`

```
val = Validator(digit=True, short=True)
words = "An apple a day is 20 dollars a month"
print(val(words))
# ["apple", "day", "dollars", "month"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating a new (and potentially long) list, you can instead make a generator function with `yield` for each succeeded word instead of `return` for a whole list:

```
class Validator(object):
  def __init__(self, digit=False, tag=False, short=False, *more_filters):
    self.digit = digit
    self.tag = tag
    self.short = short
    self.more_filters= more_filters

  def __call__(self, words):
    for word in words:
      if self.digit:
        if word.is_digit(): continue
      if self.tag:
        if word[0] == "<": continue
      if self.short:
        if len(word) < 3: continue
      if any(f(word) for f in self.more_filters):
        continue
      yield word
```

Use:

```
other_tests = [lambda w: w.startswith('#'), lambda w: w.endswith('?')]
val = Validator(digit=True, short=True, *other_tests)
words = "An apple a day is 20 dollars a month #healty toomuch? livelong!"
print(val(words))
# apple day dollars month livelong!
```

Comment: I could, and thank you for suggestion :) but I can't and this isn't an answer what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. Do you _have_ to use the ``__call__()`` method?

Comment: No, don't have. Why? Is it bad? I like it on single purpose classes.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't think it's bad. (I just checked and there's no problem using ``__call__`` as a generator function either.) I was just curious about your desired solution.

Comment: I've edited the answer to accept various other filters/flags. Not sure if your various flags are fixed or not. I'll guess other might have more to add. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Element by element approach using python filter

```
from itertools import filterfalse

class Validator(object):
  def __init__(self, digit=False, tag=False, short=False):
    self.digit = digit
    self.tag = tag
    self.short = short

  def __call__(self, word):
    if self.digit:
      if word.isdigit(): return True
    if self.tag:
      if word[0] == "<": return True
    if self.short:
      if len(word) < 3: return True
    return False

val = Validator(digit=True, short=True)
words = "An apple a day is 20 dollars a month".split()
assert list(filter(val, words)) == ['An', 'a', 'is', '20', 'a']
assert list(filterfalse(val, words)) == ['apple', 'day', 'dollars', 'month']
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of `filter` and `filterfalse`. The question is whether these are better then simple iteration and why? Actually, question is what's the optimal approach to filtering list with statement depending on configuration.

Comment: Optimal with regard to what? Speed, memory usage, readability, extensibility, ...? You should phrase your question more clearly.

Comment: I'm referring to optimal in processing (speed) sense. I've updated question. Thanks for pointing this out.